# Retuning columns in a numpy array given a boolean index

Tags: python, numpy

I have the given dataset:

```
data = np.array([
    [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1],
    [3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5],
    [6, 1, 2 ,3, 1, 3, 1]])

cols_idx = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

I want to return columns from `data` where `cols_idx == 1`. For that I used:

```
data[:, np.nonzero(cols_idx)]
```

But it returns a 3D instead a 2D array:

```
data[:, np.nonzero(cols_idx)]
array([[[1, 1]],    
       [[1, 2]],
       [[2, 1]],    
       [[2, 1]]])

data[:, np.nonzero(cols_idx)].shape
(4, 1, 2)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
data[:, np.nonzero(cols_idx)]
array([[1, 1],    
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1],    
       [2, 1]])

data[:, np.nonzero(cols_idx)].shape
(4, 2)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look at `np.nonzero(cols_idx)` by itself.

Comment: found `np.flatnonzero()` that fix the "issue"

Comment: `flatnonzero` extracts the array from the `nonzero` tuple, with a `[0]` indexing.  Look at its code!  You want to index with the array nonzero produces, not the tuple it is wrapped in.  That tuple if great for indexing by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(np.nonzero(cols_idx))` gives `(array([2, 4]),)` (a tuple rather than just an array)

So you should use `np.nonzero(cols_idx)[0] # gives [2 4]` to get what you want:

**Full code:**

```
import numpy as np 
data = np.array([
    [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1],
    [3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5],
    [6, 1, 2 ,3, 1, 3, 1]])

cols_idx = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
new_data = data[:, np.nonzero(cols_idx)[0]]
print(new_data)
'''[[1 1]                                                                                                                        
 [1 2]                                                                                                                        
 [2 1]                                                                                                                        
 [2 1]]'''
print(new_data.shape) # (4,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

From `numpy` documentation:

> While the nonzero values can be obtained with a[nonzero(a)], it is recommended to use x[x.astype(bool)] or x[x != 0] instead, which will correctly handle 0-d arrays.

So it's better to use:

```
data[:, cols_idx.astype(bool)]
```

or

```
data[:, cols_idx != 0]
```